# Google map showing only gray tiles while running with Eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I generated an Android key using the sha 1 certificate for debug keystore. 
I used that api key in my xml 
I could not get the overlay of map. 
Instead of it I got the gray tiles only.

**Errors:**

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

IOException processing: 26

java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3

```
android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)

android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)

android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)

android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)

android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
```

Comment: What version of Maps Android API are you using?

Comment: i thought that the eclipse-emulator doesnt work with Google-Maps-API at all.

Comment: show you class code, layout code and manifest file code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you generated the SHA1 key right?
Try this code to be sure:

```
private void getShaKey() {

 try {
 PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR.Package.Name",
 PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
 for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
 md.update(signature.toByteArray());
 Log.v(TAG, "KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),
 Base64.DEFAULT));
 }
 } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

 }
```

If it doesn't help, please attach your java code, layout xml, logcat output and manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

If you pretty sure your SHA1 key is correct than make sure you turn on "Google Maps Android API v2" service instead of "Google Maps API v2".  And use your SHA1 key with your application name to apply new Android key to use in your application

Answer (score 0):

Raj. I had a similar issue getting them working in my application. Unfortunately, there is a heavy emphasis on the API key generation, which is fairly straightforward...and this same symptom will persist, even if your key is proper...but, you do not have all the other components in place. This tutorial is what finally worked for me....I think my issue was not referencing the updated Google Play library in my workspace properly. I resolved that by using the Eclipse ADT SDK Manager to remove and reinstall the Google Play library project.

I am considering writing my own tutorial to include screen shots from the Eclipse IDE, which is also a new experience for me. Perhaps getting your app going will provide some structure to that process, but....Ms. Smith has written a very nice tutorial that worked for me and I am not that bright to begin with. ;-)

[Recent tutorial by Sue Smith at mobile tuts+](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/)